# Image file locked after loading in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, image, file, locked

I am reading my WPF imagesource like this:

**VB**

```
Dim bmi As BitmapImage = New BitmapImage
bmi.BeginInit
bmi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None
bmi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache
bmi.UriSource = New Uri(input.FullName, UriKind.Absolute)
bmi.EndInit
```

**C#**

```
BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
bmi.BeginInit();
bmi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
bmi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bmi.UriSource = new Uri(input.FullName,  UriKind.Absolute);
bmi.EndInit();
```

It works like it should until this point.
But user can update the image by copying the file.
Then I want to refresh the image. But the file "MyFileName" is locked and when I want do overwrite it, it throws an error that it is already in use and locked.

But wait, I searched here for a solution and I got it:

```
bmi.cachoption = OnLoad
```

was the key... BUT!! now, the image is always the old one and is not updated to the new file.
How to clear this cache?

In VB.Net I made an System.Drawing.Bitmap from stream. How to do it best way in WPF?

Regards

Comment: see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097152/creating-wpf-bitmapimage-from-memorystream-png-gif helps? i don't know how to clear the cache explicity, but this may help you anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

dlev had a good advice. Here you see the cache option that should solve it: [Problems overwriting (re-saving) image when it was set as image source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688545/wpf-problems-overwriting-re-saving-image-when-it-was-set-as-image-source)

```
imgTemp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
```