# Why is my images locked by another process?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have built a digital signage solution running in WPF. I have an executable that handles scheduling and a number of external assemblies (.dll with user controls) that is responsible of displaying an image, a video etc.

When the application starts it loads all the assemblies into a list and then uses an XML file with configuration info on which kind of slide to start with which parameters, like this:

```
<signage>
  <slide type="image" argument="c:\image1.png"/>
  <slide type="image" argument="c:\image2.png"/>
  <slide type="video" argument="c:\video1.mpg"/>
  ...
</signage>
```

That list can be very long and contain many different slides. When i build my list of objects to show i  create a new instance, via reflection, of the .dll that i need to show, passing it the argument. This is contained within a list. The parent executable is then traversing the list and displaying the user control instances (the instantiated slide types) on my main WPF application.

Thats the background for my question.

When i need to update the contents on runtime i need to replace the files on disk (image1, image2 etc...) but get an exception that the files are in use by another process and that i cannot access them.

Any idea on how to fix this? Is there any way i can "unload" them from my application? Is there any way to do this in a proper way?

**EDIT**
Here is some additional info on how i do this in an image assembly:

```
public ImageExtensionControl(XmlDocument document, Dictionary<string, string> settings, Action slideFinished)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string path = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location).Directory.FullName;
            string id = settings["Image"];
            path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, document.SelectSingleNode("properties/files/file[@id='" + id + "']").Attributes["path"].Value);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
            this.myimage.Source = bitmapImage;
        }
```

Comment: To state the obvious: maybe they are open with Windows Picture Viewer, another copy of your app, or maybe you don't close a stream using it.  If they've just been written to, it could be antivirus/security software holding it open.  The same message also applies if someone has it open over a network share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly try caching options:
[Problems overwriting (re-saving) image when it was set as image source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688545/problems-overwriting-re-saving-image-when-it-was-set-as-image-source)

```
imgTemp = new BitmapImage();
imgTemp.BeginInit();
imgTemp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
imgTemp.CreateOption = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
imgTemp.UriSource = uriSource;
imgTemp.EndInit();
imgAsset.Source = imgTemp;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're loading your images in, ensure you are closing the stream once you're finished with your operation.  For instance,

```
using(var fs = new FileStream(...))
{
   // ...
}  // <-- Stream is closed and disposed.
```

Comment: Im using a <image> component in my xaml. Its in the user control, i dont know if thats the problem?