# updating an image in an image control

Tags: c#, wpf, image

im trying to update an image in an image control that is bound to a class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. i've tried most of the methods which relate to refreshing bitmap cache so that the image can refresh but none seems to work for my case. the image contorl is defined in the xaml file as: `<Image Source="{Binding Chart}" Margin="0 0 0 0"/>` 
and in the code behind the class is:

```
 private ImageSource imagechart = null;

    public ImageSource Chart
    {
        get
        {
            return imagechart;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != imagechart)
            {
                imagechart = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Chart");

            }

        }
    }
```

after an event i now set the image using the following code:

```
c.Chart = image;
```

when i now run my application this will display the image but during the running of the application i update the image but calling this `c.Chart = image;` displays the initial image. i came to understand that WPF caches the image but all methods claiming to solve this dint work for me. one of the solutions that did not work for me is [Problems overwriting (re-saving) image when it was set as image source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688545/problems-overwriting-re-saving-image-when-it-was-set-as-image-source)

Comment: try to make the binding TwoWay:  Image Source="{Binding Chart, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: that did not work either..i want the image control to refresh the image without having to close the application since when i rerun the app the image will appear as updated

Comment: Just asking....  Are all the other bindings on your app working as expected?

Comment: how are you creating your imagesource.. can you share the code?

Comment: @GarryVass all the other bindings are working as expected

Comment: @nit i'm creating my imagesource as follows:                           private ImageSource imageeabl = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/eabl.jpg"));

Comment: can you test if instead of binding to Bitmapimage...bind your imagesource to the string returning the image path i.e pack://application:,,,/Resources/eabl.jpg..

Comment: @nit still not updating the image. the image only updates when you exit and restart the application

Comment: what is the buildAction of your images?

Comment: buildAction is set to resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your input coz through them i finally figure a way around this. so my xaml still remains bound as `<Image Source="{Binding Chart}"  Margin="0 0 0 0"/>` but in the code behind i changed the class property chart to return a bitmap as shown below:

```
  private BitmapImage image = null;

    public BitmapImage Chart
    {
        get
        {
            return image;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != image)
            {
                image = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Chart");

            }

        }
    }
```

this class mind you implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` . at the point where i set the image i am now using this code:

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
img.BeginInit();
img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
//in the following code path is a string where i have defined the path to file
img.UriSource = new Uri(string.Format("file://{0}",path));
img.EndInit();
c.Chart = img;
```

this works well for me and refreshes the image upon update.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the return Type of your `Image` property to `Uri`. The TypeConverter on the Source Property should do the rest. If this doesnt work, verify that the resource has actually changed.

You can read the resource from your assembly using Assembly.GetManifestResourceStreams and resolve the bytes. Than manually save them with File.WriteAllBytes to your output directory an see if it has the expected image.

As far as i know Application Ressources (which are embedded into the assembly) can not be changed during runtime (?). You are referencing the assembly ressource and not an output ressource with your pack uri.

Comment: thanks you gave me an idea and changed the property to return a `BitmapImage`.check the answer i just posted for more details.