# How to refresh image in Image control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a desktop viewer. I managed to take a single screenshot and put it into an Image control. But if I try to repeat it, the program freezes and the image doesn't appear.

```
private void Display()
{
    img.Source = ScreenImage(); // returns BitmapImage
}

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    while(true)
    {  
        Display();
    }
}
```

If I run Display method once it works, but after calling it more times it doesn't show anything.

Comment: That `while(true)` is choking your program. Remove the `while(true)`

Comment: I think link help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112370/updating-an-image-in-an-image-control

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to replicate all visual changes to the desktop in the image control (make a movie of the desktop) instead of looping endlessly in a click

> what should happen if you click it twice (if you could click it)?

start a timer that takes a snapshot every second or so on a background thread.

That way the application will remain responsive.

Your current code is claiming the UI thread for ever and that is why you can't do anything in the application after clicking the button.